# Верхняя часть рамки (top) была картинкой?

Tags: css

`border-top: url();`  не работает

```
#body_in{
    outline:1px solid #C30;
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-top: url(../img/border_top.png);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@mi4i](/users/20430/mi4i), вы некорректно используете это свойство.
Только для одной стороны задать границу в виде картинки нельзя.
Вашу задачу можно решить, скрыв ненужные границы и используя корректное CSS-свойство:

```
#body_in{
    outline:1px solid #C30;
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-image: url(../img/border_top.png) 30 30 round;
    border-bottom:0;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:0;
}
```

**http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-image**

Comment: Его заполняет цветом background-color.как исправить ?